# Docker unable to mount volume with node app

Tags: macos, docker

I have create a local node express app and now I am trying to run the node app via Docker.

```
docker run -p 8080:3000 -v $(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" node npm start
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.0.3
npm info using node@v8.1.2
npm ERR! path /var/www/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Host: MAC
Using Docket toolbox to create  the container.

application runs locally but do not start via docker.

Any idea?
docker inspect <> Does show the mount

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Jsapp/ExpressSite",
                "Destination": "/var/www",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
```

Comment: `docker run -p 8080:3000 -v $(pwd):/var/www node npm start -- -w "/var/www"`

Comment: `docker run -p 8080:3000 -v $(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" node ls -la` Do you see the package.json file?

Comment: @German docker run -p 8080:3000 -v $(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" node ls -la output has No package.json

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Same error

Comment: Have you package.json into the folder are you running the command?

Comment: @German In local set my express application is working, I have docker's node image and now setting up the container . I am running cmd from current dir ..

Comment: This is strange, because in the way you are mounting the volume, if you have a "package.json" it would have to be in the directory as well.

Comment: Try this `touch hello && docker run -it -v $(pwd):/tmp -w /tmp ubuntu ls -la`

Comment: @German can it be a permission issue ?? when I try mapping volumn in kitematics it say either dir do not exists or make sure you can read or write..

Comment: the command works for me

Comment: Could by a permisson problems.... but try to execute the command i give you into /tmp folder to know if it's right.